# heroku run rake db:migrate doesn't find app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake

I've tried everything - I always get Timeout waiting dyno or App not found.

[image]
[image]

can someone please help me use the right syntax or something - what in the world could I be doing wrong??

Here are some links that haven't helped:

> https://twitter.com/viktorbenei/status/456913389928054784
>   [heroku : run rake db:migrate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003881/heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-error)
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos
>   https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=how+to+deploy+rails+app+to+heroku+rake+db&oq=how+to+deploy+rails+app+to+heroku+rake+db&gs_l=serp.3...1923.3702.0.3978.8.8.0.0.0.0.258.775.0j4j1.5.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..5.3.520.88zR1b0gS6c
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake
>   [Heroku run rake db:migrate results in no change in the database, app restarted several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737800/heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-results-in-no-change-in-the-database-app-restarted-s)

Comment: Have you tried logging into bash on that app and doing it from there? `heroku run bash --app your_app_name` then try running your rake command.

Comment: does `heroku run rake db:migrate --remote heroku` work? Or whatever your heroku remote is called.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that I was trying to do this at work. I thought that it was communicating with the server because it would say things like app not found but it actually wasn't. when I tried this at home it worked fine.